# How to sum to one column other column from a diffrent file?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have something like this

file1:

```
element1,12
element2,10
element3,5
```

file2:

```
IN
element1,8
element3,5
```

and I want to modify file1 and obtain:

```
element1,20
element2,10
element3,10
```

The first line from file2 contains "IN" that, means I want to make an addition. If it would have been "OUT" instead, the values should be subtracted and file1 should have looked like this:

```
element1,4
element2,10
element3,0
```

I have to work with awk, grep, sed.
Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
        mult = ($1=="IN" ? 1 : -1)
    }
    else {
        add[$1] = mult * $2
    }
    next
}
{
    $2 += add[$1]
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
element1,20
element2,10
element3,10
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file3 file1
element1,4
element2,10
element3,0
```

```
$ head file{1..3}
==> file1 <==
element1,12
element2,10
element3,5

==> file2 <==
IN
element1,8
element3,5

==> file3 <==
OUT
element1,8
element3,5
```